# Putting the array back together

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am trying to write a class to allow you to set up a relationship between two models in a php MVC based project. I want to create a custom object that has only the fields you want in it So I wrote this:

```
class CreateRelationShipObjects {

    private $modelObjects;

    public function __construct($modelObjects){
        if(is_array($modelObjects) && isset($modelObjects)){
            $this->modelObjects = $modelObjects;
        }
    }

    public function createRelationShip($columns){
        if(is_array($columns)){
           foreach($columns as $custom_name=>$column){
               foreach($this->modelObjects as $name => $modelObject){
                   $this->checkForColumnInModelObject($modelObject, $column, $custom_name);
               }
           } 
        }
    }

    private function checkForColumnInModelObject($modelObject, $column, $custom_name){
        $relationship = array();
        if(property_exists($modelObject, $column)){
            $value_returned = $modelObject->$column;
            $relationship = array($column => $value_returned);
            var_dump($relationship);
        }
        //return $this->toObj($relationship);
    }

    private function toObj($releationshipArray){
       //var_dump((Object)$releationshipArray);
    }
}
```

The idea is that you use the class as such:

```
 $relationship = new CreateRelationShipObjects(array(
     'equipment_ip_models' => $equipmentIpModels,
     'site_models' => $siteModel,
     'equipment_models' => $equipmentModel
 ));

 $relationship->createRelationShip(array(
     'equipment_model' => 'model',
     'equipment_manufacture' => 'manufacture',
     'equipment_ip' => 'ipAddress',
     'site_name' => 'name',
     'site_id' => 'code'
 ));
```

In the class above we will go through looking in each model supplied for the column. and then give you back an object that looks exactly like the "template" you supplied in `createRelationShip`

The problem is, I am getting back, with my `var_dump`, an arrays like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["model"]=>
  string(13) "4168.21.33.03"
}

array(1) {
  ["manufacture"]=>
  string(6) "ALLGON"
}

// ... And so on
```

The array should look like:

```
array(
    'equipment_model' => '4168.21.33.03',
    'equipment_manufacture' => 'ALLGON',
    // .. and so on ... 
);
```

**Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: What are you `var_dump`ing?

Comment: @Neal Please see updated OP, its the first `var_dump` that's giving the arrays you see `var_dump`ed. I also updated what I expect to get back, as opposed to what I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works better? If you modify these two functions?

```
public function createRelationShip($columns){
    if(is_array($columns)){
       $relationship = array();
       foreach($columns as $custom_name=>$column){
           foreach($this->modelObjects as $name => $modelObject){
               $relationship += $this->checkForColumnInModelObject($modelObject, $column, $custom_name);
           }
       } 
       var_dump($relationship);
    }
}

private function checkForColumnInModelObject($modelObject, $column, $custom_name){
    if(property_exists($modelObject, $column)){
        $value_returned = $modelObject->$column;
        return array($column => $value_returned);
    }
    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class below is essentially what I needed to do this. it took me the entire night but I wrote it. It takes in what I pass it and gives me back one object like what I want.

```
class RelationshipObject {
  /**
   * Stores the models
   * 
   * @var type 
   */  
  private $modelObjects;

  /**
   * Takes in the objects
   * 
   * @param array $objects
   */
  public function __construct($objects) {
    $this->modelObjects = $objects;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a custom object based on the array passed in.
   * 
   * @param array $outputKeysToInputKeys
   * @return obj
   */
  public function create(array $outputKeysToInputKeys) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($outputKeysToInputKeys as $outputKey => $inputKey) {
      foreach ($this->modelObjects as $object) {
        if (property_exists($object, $inputKey))
          $result[$outputKey] = $object->$inputKey;
      }
    }

    return $this->to_obj($result);
  }

  /**
   * Converts an array to an object.
   * 
   * @param array $array
   * @return obj
   */
  public function to_obj($array){
      return (Object)$array;
  }
}
```